# How to use progress bar to show loading of RSS Feeds with MVVM pattern using async

Tags: c#

I am creating an application with MVVM pattern in which i need to load data from RSS feed. It takes some time so I want to use Progress bar to show loading process. How can I achieve this through async and IsBusy status using MVVM pattern in view model? Please provide code if anybody is having. 
On UI code for Progress Bar is:

```
<ProgressBar IsIndeterminate={Binding IsBusy} />
```

what should be the code in ViewModel for it?

Answer (score 1):

You should also bind `Visibility` attribute. And because it expects `Visibility` enum values you have to use [`BooleanToVisibilityConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx) converter:

```
<Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibility" />
</Resources>

<ProgressBar IsIndeterminate={Binding IsBusy}
             Visibility="{Binding IsBusy, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibility}}" />
```

Comment: Thanx for your answer. Please can you provide code for viewmodel to handle Progress Bar

Answer (score 0):

Fo your ViewModel, you simply need an IsBusy property which triggers a `NotifyPropertyChanged` event.

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _isBusy;

    public bool IsBusy
    {
        get { return _isBusy; }
        set
        {
            _isBusy = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("IsBusy");
        }
    }

    private void BeginWorking()
    {
        this.IsBusy = true;
        //Do the work...
    }
    private void FinishWorking()
    {
        this.IsBusy = false;
    }

    //Other implementation, including INotifyPropertyChanged...
}
```

If you're not familiar with implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`, there are numerous resources out there to help with that.

As one of the previous answers suggests, you'll need to use the `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` to convert from the `bool` value to the `Visibility` value to show/hide the `ProgressBar`.

Also, the changes to your UI won't be reflected unless you do the work of retrieving the RSS Feed from a background thread.  Otherwise, you will block the UI thread, and your UI won't be updated.